# scrolling animate marginTop problems

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, scroll

I have this code and

.cscc

```
.messages{
   width:95%;
   height:200px;
   overflow:auto;
 }
.message{
   width:98%;
 &:hover{
   background: #d6d6f0;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
}
.message-author{
    float:left;
}
.message-date{
 float:right;
 }
.message-header{
    display:block;
}
.message-content{
    padding:1em
}
```

html.erb

```
<div class="messages" data-url="<%= dialog_url @dialog_user %>">
<div id="messages-container">
<% @messages.each do |msg| %>
    <div class="message">
    <div class="message-header">
        <div class="message-author"> <%= msg.from.username %> </div>
            <div class="message-date"> <%= msg.created_at %> </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="message-content"> <%= msg.body %> </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

js

```
jQuery ->
 $(document).ready ->
$(".messages").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#b8b8b8"})

val1 = $("#messages-container").height()
val2 = $(".message").last().height()
val = val1 - val2 - 100

$("#messages-container").animate marginTop: "-=" + val + "px"
```

when js animate is completed i losted ability to scrolling div

some helpfup pics
[image: pic1]

or you can just see the problem here ccc-chat.herokuapp.com (sign up with any fake email)

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. I've visited the site, no animation happens. The scroll keeps doing what it should do.

Comment: Just for others: username sdsd / email row@example.com / pass ikbennietgek .. skip the sign up part :)

Comment: wow. i doesn't noticed that resources not complied.
trying to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Fix it.
Forgot to deploy last commit.
Now works